# Add custom theme variable in createTheme()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By default the MUI theme is a combination of several pre-defined objects such as `typography: {...}`, `palette: {...}` etc.

Is is possible to add a custom object into this setup and still use `createTheme`?

So for example the theme object would become:

```
const theme = {
  palette: {
    primary: '#000'
  },
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontFamily: 'Comic Sans'
    }
  },
  custom: {
    myOwnComponent: {
      margin: '10px 10px'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, this works just fine. Material-UI does a [deep merge of its defaults](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.js#L44) with the object you provide with some special handling for keys that get merged in a more sophisticated fashion (such as `palette`, `typography` and a few others). Any unrecognized keys will come through unchanged.

Below is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  useTheme,
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#00F"
    }
  },
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontFamily: "Comic Sans"
    }
  },
  custom: {
    myOwnComponent: {
      margin: "10px 10px",
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
    }
  }
});
const MyOwnComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <div style={theme.custom.myOwnComponent}>
      Here is my own component using a custom portion of the theme.
    </div>
  );
};
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          <Typography variant="body1">
            Button using main theme color and font-family
          </Typography>
        </Button>
        <MyOwnComponent />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit custom properties in theme]

Comment: I believe the ability to do this has been deleted. I'm trying to do it in my code using Typescript and I'm getting an error that `custom` is not included in `ThemeOptions`. This may be just a typescript issue but wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this.

Comment: @CWSites not sure if you cared, but I got a typescript solution working. In my `theme.ts` file, if you ```declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    customthing: string;
  }
  interface ThemeOptions {
    customthing?: string;
  }
}```

then you can 

```const theme = createMuiTheme({
   customthing: 'red',
   ...otherOverRides
})```

Comment: what about typescirpt?

Comment: Here's the documentation for how to do this in typescript:
https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme

Answer (score 17):

You can add custom variables in your MUI theme as easy as:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  myField: {
    myNestedField: 'myValue',
  },
});
```

But if you're using Typescript, you also need to update the definition of `ThemeOptions` and `Theme` using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  // fix the type error when referencing the Theme object in your styled component
  interface Theme {
    myField?: {
      myNestedField?: string;
    };
  }
  // fix the type error when calling `createTheme()` with a custom theme option
  interface ThemeOptions {
    myField?: {
      myNestedField?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

If you want to reuse the type between `Theme` and `ThemeOptions`, you can define a common interface and inherit it in both places:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface CustomTheme {
    myField?: {
      myNestedField?: string;
    };
  }

  interface Theme extends CustomTheme {}
  interface ThemeOptions extends CustomTheme {}
}
```

Also note that you don't have to create custom variables in MUI theme if you want to override a custom component using `createTheme()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69455458/9449426) answer for more detail.

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Make sure to add `declare module @mui/material/styles { ... }` in the file where you are creating the theme (invoking the function `createTheme()`)

Comment: Can I somehow make the module augmentation global? I've tried putting this into a theme.d.ts file but the type inference doesn't carry over. 
For my case I want to use the Theme in a lot of places so starting each file with the augmentation is not an option

Answer (score 2):

I use this case with typescript without any declarations:

```
const theme: Theme = createTheme({ 
  palette: {...},
  components: {...},
  ...
}, {
  customValues: {
    customKey: customValue,
  }
});
```

Then I can use it in my code so:

```
const theme = useTheme();
const myCustomValueFromTheme = theme.customValues.customKey;
```

Or you can use it in your styles for example like this:

```
const StyledContainer: StyledComponent<any, any> = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.customValues.customKey};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answers above, if you are using sx for styling you can access the custom theme like so:

```
<div sx={{ margin: (theme) => theme.custom.myOwnComponent.margin }} />
```