# Override Box component in createTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themeprovider

I have an application that utilizes box's in place of where divs would typically be placed to stay within the MUI ecosystem. My question is, is it possible to have a global theme override for all box components much like how you can globally override the background color for all cards using theme provider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the `Card` styles globally using `createTheme()` because the `Card` has a [name](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cd6281d04f23f702fc254c494859f197308ed0fe/packages/mui-material/src/Card/Card.js#L22-L22) and a [`styleOverrides`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cd6281d04f23f702fc254c494859f197308ed0fe/packages/mui-material/src/Card/Card.js#L24-L24) callback when it is styled using the [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api) API. However, the `Box` does not, as you can see from the definition [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cd6281d04f23f702fc254c494859f197308ed0fe/packages/mui-system/src/createBox.js#L10-L10).

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // this works
    MuiCard: {
      styleOverrides: {
        //
      }
    },
    // this does not work
    MuiBox: {
      styleOverrides: {
        //
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to create a base component like the `Box` that can be styled globally by `createTheme`, you need to define the following properties in the options when calling `styled()`

- `name`: so the styled engine can identify your component.
- `overridesResolver`: to let MUI know how to resolve the final styles (by combining with other styles created by custom variant, prop and state of the component).

Below is the minimal example for demonstration:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDiv: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "green"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const Div = styled("div", {
  name: "MuiDiv",
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => {
    return [styles.root];
  }
})();
```

```
<Div sx={{ width: 10, height: 10 }} />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### References

- https://mui.com/system/styled/#api
- https://mui.com/system/styled/#custom-components